# I want to convert MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers to a Map<String,List<String>>

Tags: java

I have this

```
public Map<String,List<String>> prepareParameters(MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers) {

        Map<String, List<String>> result = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        headers.forEach((key, value) -> result.put(key.toLowerCase(), value));
        return headers;
    }
```

but I have keep getting this pmd error >Rule:UseConcurrentHashMap Priority:3 If you run in Java5 or newer and have concurrent access, you should use the ConcurrentHashMap implementation.

Comment: is that a compilation error? Or a runtime exception or error? does the code run?

Comment: If you have any examples on how it is and how you want it to be, woud be very helpful!

Comment: @f1sh it is a runtime error

Comment: If it is a runtime error, can you include the error and stacktrace?

Comment: it does not strike me as an error, otherwise you'd get an an exception with a stacktrace. Is this a warning maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be no concurrent `TreeMap` implementation, and it looks like you need the entries of this map to be sorted for some reason. Given that you know what you're doing, and that you've double checked that you are not accessing the map concurrently, you can suppress the PMD warning using:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.UseConcurrentHashMap")
public Map<String,List<String>> prepareParameters(MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers) {
    ...
}
```